# How to run a WiFi hot spot from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I am unable to start the WiFi hot spot feature from the network settings. After turning the hotspot, the dialog box confirms the WiFi hot spot is  turned on, but the connection does not appear on my phone and other wireless devices.

I use the Internet from an Ethernet LAN connection and want to share my internet connection to other wireless devices.

Comment: Does your computer have the necessary equipment to broadcast a wifi signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Disable WIFI and plug in an internet cable to your laptop so that your Ubuntu is connect to a wired internet and wireless is disabled.
   **Go to Network Icon on top panel -> Edit Connections …**, then click the Add button in the pop-up window.[image]
2. Choose Wi-Fi from the drop-down menu and click the Create button:[image]
3. In next window, do:

> Type in a connection name.
>   Select mode: Hotspot Device.
>   from drop-down menu. create-wifi-hotspotThe name will be used later.
>   Type in a SSIDMAC address: select your wireless card

[image]

4. Go to Wi-Fi Security tab, select security type WPA & WPA2 Personal and set a password.[image]
5. Go to IPv4 Settings tab, from Method drop-down box select Shared to other computers.[image]
6. When done, click the save button.
   Go to Network Icon again and you will see the created hotspot ubuntu.
   [image]
7. When everything’s done, enable WIFI from Network Manager icon on the panel. It should automatically connect to the hotspot you created. If not, select Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network … and select it from the drop-down box.[image]
8. Now you can search and connect the access point from your Android mobile and enjoy!

[Reference](http://learn.linksprite.com/project/create-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-16-04-android-support/).